# compile error when using boost::lockfree::spsc_queue (Is it a bug in boost?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I defined a variable as follow:

```
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<std::vector<char *>, boost::lockfree::capacity<10> > myVariable;
```

and in my code, I tried to rest it :

```
myVariable.reset();
```

but when I am compiling my code I am getting this error:

```
Error   17  error C2660: 'boost::lockfree::detail::ringbuffer_base<T>::pop' : function does not take 1 arguments    C:\Local\boost\boost\lockfree\spsc_queue.hpp
```

Why I am getting this error?

I am using visual studio 2013 on windows 8.1

## Edit 1:

Boost version is 1.57

Comment: Which version of boos is installed in `C:\Local\boost`

Comment: @sehe boost version added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is a bug in 1.57 and has been fixed in 1.58

Comment: Thanks, do you have any reference to that? it is not documented here: http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_58_0.html

Comment: I just compared the source. This seems to be the merge commit https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/commit/12f8d4621c9bc604285091945bf76f850b52b86e (which adds a new test case for `reset()` on a compile-time sized queue)

Comment: The actual commit is from https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/commit/6454f9fb8593243c92b6e9671961953c3cb77c96