# Make nvcc output traces on compile error

Tags: c++, cuda, compiler-errors, nvcc

I have some trouble compiling some code with nvcc. It heavily relies on templates and the like so error messages are hard to read. For example currently I'm getting a message

> /usr/include/boost/utility/detail/result_of_iterate.hpp:135:338:
>   error: invalid use of qualified-name
>   ‘std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::propagate_on_container_swap’

which is not really helpful. No information on where it came from or what the template arguments were. Compiling with e.g. gcc shows some really nice output with candidates and template arguments etc.

Is it anyhow possible to get those with nvcc too? Or at least for the host code? It is impossible to compile with gcc only as cuda functions are used which can't be eliminated.

**This question is NOT about that particular error, but on how to get more details from nvcc on ANY error. This one should only serve as an example**

Condensed working example (compile with nvcc -std=c++11):

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/utility/result_of.hpp>

struct foo{
    int operator()(int x){ return x + 42; }
};
typename boost::result_of < foo(int) >::type
bar(int x){ return foo()(x); }

int main(int argc, char**argv){
  return bar(argc);
}
```

Or even less code:

```
template<typename T>
struct TriggerError{

private:
    template<typename _Tp>
    static float helper(_Tp*);
    static int   helper(...);
    typedef decltype(helper((T*)0)) privateWrong;

public:
  typedef privateWrong SomethingWentWrong;
};

#include <boost/utility/result_of.hpp>

struct foo{
    int operator()(int x){ return x + 42; }
};

typename boost::result_of < foo(int) >::type
bar(int x){ return foo()(x); }

int main(int argc, char**argv){
  return bar(argc);
}
```

It seems, that cudafe++ replaces the "type" token with "TriggerError::SomethingWentWrong" for some reason. So this seems to be a CUDA bug.

nvcc --version: Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.27

gcc --version: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

Comment: please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that generates such a message; please also specify your CUDA and GCC version

Comment: please also read http://stackoverflow.com/a/31796410/678093

Comment: I cannot post any code as I don't know where this particular error occurs. Thats the reason why I'm asking. And I'm not asking how to solve THAT specific error, but how to get MEANINGFUL error messages. And yes it is of course possible, that its a nvcc bug with boost, but I'd need to find at least the reason. And for that I need some error messages to work with.

Comment: Actually, nvcc uses gcc under the hood to compile host code, including boost include files.  The information requested by @m.s. would actually be helpful for others trying to help you.  It would even be helpful if you would just include a bit more of the error output (the stuff preceding the line you have shown.) But this all appears to be not what you want to do.  So maybe someone else will have the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I forgot to add the compiler versions (done now). And the problem is: There is NO more error output. Just the line I posted (repeated a couple of times) nothing more.  How am I supposed to post any more message details when the question, I'm asking, is how to get more message details?<br>By analyzing the generated files I was able to boil it down to an example. Please find it in the OP

Comment: And for whoever downvoted: This question is not about this particular problem but about the general possibility to get more output from nvcc. I don't see why an actual example program is required here...

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed in cuda 7.5RC.

Comment: As a workaround for cuda 7.0 you can try to compile with `-DBOOST_NO_SFINAE_EXPR`. However, I don't know if this has sideeffects...

Comment: Including <boost/utility/result_of.hpp> as the very first include also works. I still would like to see more help from nvcc.

Comment: to be clear, nvcc is a compiler driver.  It is *not* a compiler for host code.  It takes the code you give it in a .cu file, then does some preprocessing on it, then hands it off to gcc or whatever is the host code compiler.  There is no way to ask for more information from nvcc about the error generated, because the errors generated *are not emanating from nvcc*.  They are emanating from gcc.  Yes, the nvcc preprocessing has apparently munged the file, which is a bug, which now appears to be fixed in CUDA 7.5, but your request for "more help from nvcc" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The comparison to gcc you've made is specious, because gcc doesn't thrown any errors with the given file.  If you were to take the given file, and modify it the way nvcc does during preprocessing, then attempt to feed it to gcc the way nvcc does, I claim you would get the *exact same output* from gcc.  So the comparison suggesting that gcc is great is apples-to-oranges, because your gcc test case that produces any sort of error output is a *different test case*.

Comment: Well then this is the answer: It's just not possible to get more ouput because I already get the gcc output. This is what I wanted to know. It could have been that there were some obscure compiler flags that are not documented or not easy to find which I can use. But if there aren't, its ok. Then I won't have to look further. The reason for this SPECIFIC error is that cudafe++ made something invalid that produced wrong syntax, which is what gcc is complaining about. However this is not what you expect. I'd expected some invalid template instantiation and was looking for help/more info on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the main question: There is no flag or anything that makes nvcc output more template information than there already is. The error shown is a syntax error rather than a template instantiation error but it is caused by a bug in CUDA 7.0.

Information on the bug for reference:
The bug occurs only in CUDA 7.0. It was not there in CUDA 6.5 and is fixed in CUDA 7.5RC and up. It only affects C++11 compilation mode (trying to compile the above code in C++98 is supposed to fail) The bug also occurs only with boost 1.5x (possibly 1.50 latest 1.52) where the decltype usage for boost::result_of was introduced. A more minimal example: [Compilation error with nvcc and c++11, need minimal failing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969644/compilation-error-with-nvcc-and-c11-need-minimal-failing-example)

There are 3 possible work-arounds:

1. Use `std::result_of` (c++11)
2. Include `<boost/utility/result_of.hpp>` as the very first include
3. Use the boost TR1 protocol and define `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1`