# Compilation error with nvcc and c++11, need minimal failing example

Tags: c++11, boost, cuda, nvcc

The following code (originally from Boost) fails to compile using nvcc 7.0 with C++11 support enabled:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct result_of_always_void
{
    typedef void type;
};

template<typename F, typename Enable = void> struct cpp0x_result_of_impl {};

template<typename F,typename T0>
struct cpp0x_result_of_impl<F(T0), typename result_of_always_void< decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T0 >()))>::type >
{
    typedef decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T0 >())) type;
};


int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
test.cu:16:93: error: invalid use of qualified-name ‘std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::propagate_on_container_swap’
   typedef decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T0 >())) type;
                                                                                             ^
```

I suspect this is due to a bug in the nvcc compiler, but before I file a bug, I wanted to ask if it is possible to simplify the code further while still having it produce the error?

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE. Has the same issue in boost alone, so the following might be helpful to others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940457/make-nvcc-output-traces-on-compile-error?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue appears to be fixed in cuda 7.5RC.  Please switch to the newer cuda version.

```
$ cat t877.cu
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct result_of_always_void
{
    typedef void type;
};

template<typename F, typename Enable = void> struct cpp0x_result_of_impl {};

template<typename F,typename T0>
struct cpp0x_result_of_impl<F(T0), typename result_of_always_void< decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T0 >()))>::type >
{
    typedef decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T0 >())) type;
};


int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
$ /usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Feb_16_22:59:02_CST_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.27
$ /usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc -std=c++11 t877.cu -o t877
t877.cu:14:93: error: invalid use of qualified-name âstd::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::propagate_on_container_swapâ
     typedef decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T0 >())) type;
                                                                                             ^
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_May__7_00:35:41_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.6
$ nvcc -std=c++11 t877.cu -o t877
$
```

You're welcome to file a bug, of course.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I see you're affiliated with Nvidia; would there be any point in filing this considering it being solved?

Comment: I think it's likely that if you filed a bug, that you would get a response similar to what I posted here: "It seems to be fixed in a newer version, can you try that?"  Beyond that, some organizations like to have official communication/acknowledgment from NVIDIA (which my posting here is not) when they have reported an issue; reporting a bug should get you that.  In any event, thanks for identifying any issues you find (rather than ignoring them or just working around them).  That helps to create a better tool for others to use in the future.

Comment: By the way, this code is definitely short enough to demonstrate the issue. Hypothetically speaking, if you had identified this issue and reduced it to this level, and wanted to file a bug, you should just do so. The demonstrator is short enough. Nobody at NVIDIA is going to say "please provide a more minimal code", given this example that you already have.  However posting here is not a bad idea because it may save you time in discovering a workaround, and also if you have made a mistake others may spot it. However a host code like this that compiles with gcc but not nvcc is likely a nvcc bug.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I think I will leave it at this. The information is now available for others here, and there is a clear solution to the problem.